# Conflito de margem em css

Tags: html, css

Bom tenho 2 classes sendo:
1 - `container` que recebe algumas informações
2 - `top_menu` que recebe o menu.

Não sei explicar como isso ocorre, mas sempre que eu coloco uma div com a classe `container` o menu cria uma margem no topo.

alguém sabe o porque que isso acontece?

Se remover a div `container` o menu fica sem margem, do jeito certo. Porém preciso da div `container`.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    color:#484848;
    font-family: 'Verdana', sans-serif;
}
.container {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 10px auto 10px auto;
    width: 95%;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
}
.top_menu {
    width: 100%;
}
ul.horizontal-menu, .horizontal-menu ul  {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.horizontal-menu {
    float: left;
    width:100%;
    background: #616161;
}
.horizontal-menu li {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    padding: 25px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -webkit-transition: border-color .218s;
    -moz-transition: border .218s;
    -o-transition: border-color .218s;
    transition: border-color .218s;
    background: #616161;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.horizontal-menu li .material-icons {
    margin: -10px;
}
.hideshow ul li {
    width: 250px;
    text-align: center;
}
.horizontal-menu li:hover {
    border-bottom: 3px solid rgb(246,83,20);
    padding-bottom: 22px;
    background: #484848;
}
.horizontal-menu li.hideshow ul {
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    left: -203px;
    width: 300px;
}
.horizontal-menu li.hideshow {
    position:relative;
}
.hideshow ul {
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    background: #616161;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
    margin-top: 25px;
}
.top_menu_extra {
    background-color: #616161;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
    border: 0 solid #484848;
    border-top-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Top Menu -->
<div class="top_menu">
  <ul class="horizontal-menu">
    <li id="sub">&nbsp;<i class="material-icons">search</i>&nbsp;</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 1</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 2</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 3</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 4</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 5</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 6</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 7</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 8</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 9</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 10</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 11</li>
  </ul>
</div>


<!-- Container -->
<div class="container">
  Container
</div>

<h1 class="txt-center">TEXTO</h1>
```

Comment: No seu CSS, o `.container` tem margem no topo.

Comment: não. coloquei o css da div `container` na pergunta.

Comment: Então: `margin: 10px auto 10px auto;`. O primeiro 10px é no topo.

Comment: o menu esta fora do  `.container` esse e o problema. o menu tem que estar no topo sem margem, e depois tem que vim o `.container` com a margem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Editado!**

Para corrigir isso. Remova os `float: left` das classes `.horizontal-menu` e `.horizontal-menu li` e adicione `display: display: inline-block;` nessas duas classes. Veja abaixo:

```css
body {
margin: 0;
color:#484848;
font-family: 'Verdana', sans-serif;
}
.container {
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin: 10px auto 10px auto;
width: 95%;
border-radius: 4px;
background: #FFFFFF;
}
.top_menu {
width: 100%;
}
ul.horizontal-menu, .horizontal-menu ul  {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
.horizontal-menu {
display: inline-block;
width:100%;
background: #616161;
}
.horizontal-menu li {
display: inline-block;
padding: 25px;
color: #FFFFFF;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
-webkit-transition: border-color .218s;
-moz-transition: border .218s;
-o-transition: border-color .218s;
transition: border-color .218s;
background: #616161;
cursor: pointer;
}
.horizontal-menu li .material-icons {
margin: -10px;
}
.hideshow ul li {
width: 250px;
text-align: center;
}
.horizontal-menu li:hover {
border-bottom: 3px solid rgb(246,83,20);
padding-bottom: 22px;
background: #484848;
}
.horizontal-menu li.hideshow ul {
position:absolute;
display:none;
left: -203px;
width: 300px;
}
.horizontal-menu li.hideshow {
position:relative;
}
.hideshow ul {
padding-bottom: 7px;
background: #616161;
border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
margin-top: 25px;
}
.top_menu_extra {
background-color: #616161;
width: 100%;
display: none;
border: 0 solid #484848;
border-top-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Top Menu -->
<div class="top_menu">
  <ul class="horizontal-menu">
    <li id="sub">&nbsp;<i class="material-icons">search</i>&nbsp;</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 1</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 2</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 3</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 4</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 5</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 6</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 7</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 8</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 9</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 10</li>
    <li data-link="http://www.google.com">MENU 11</li>
  </ul>
</div>


<!-- Container -->
<div class="container">
  Container
</div>

<h1 class="txt-center">TEXTO</h1>
```

Comment: Isso resolve em parte, pois atrapalha o alinhamento da div `container`. Quero resolver isso sem mexer na div `container`. o que não entendo é o que ela tem aver com o menu no topo. acho que o problema esta no menu.

Comment: Neste caso você pode remover os float: left das classes: ".horizontal-menu" e ".horizontal-menu li" e adicionar: "display: display: inline-block;" nessas duas classes! vou editar. Veja

Comment: Eu prefiro utilizar display: inline-block ao invés de float: left. Eu acho muito mais fácil de trabalhar e deis de que passei a usar nunca mais tive problemas como os que eu sempre tinha quando utilizava float.